# java.lang.String cannot be cast error

Tags: java, string, hibernate, casting, scrollableresults

I have a DAO method:

```
     Criteria crit = statelessSession.createCriteria(APRecord.class, "apr");
     crit.createAlias("mAId", "mId", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);

     rit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("pName"), "pName")
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("kNum"), "kNum")
        .add(Projections.countDistinct("agentG"), "count"));

           return crit.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

This returns me an error:

```
      java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to test.model.AR.APRecord
```

Anyone know what the error is? any help appreciated

Comment: Please send the full stack strace and also you entire method. What is the return type of your method ?

Comment: Plz add full stack trace.

Comment: Please try use "APRecord" instead of APRecord.class

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in this line:

```
Criteria crit = statelessSession.createCriteria(APRecord.class, "apr");
```

Basically you are trying to cast a string `"apr"` to `APRecord.class`

You can find [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) some examples for criteria usages.